# scp files from multiple nodes to one and removing them on the others

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my syntax. When I /usr/bin/scp multiple files (with different names) in a for loop I only get one file in the intended directory instead of the multiple. Please advise.

```
for HOST in $HOST_LIST
do
   ssh $HOST "ls /hello/world/temp/glout/filename_ofmultiplefiles*.txt"
   RESULT=`echo $?`
   if [[ $RESULT = "0" ]]
      then
      for FILE in `ssh $HOST "ls /hello/world/temp/glout/filename_ofmultiplefiles*.txt"`
         do
         ssh $HOST "/usr/bin/scp $FILE app4:/home/sftp/jo/horizon/"
         echo "Moved file $FILE from $HOST to /home/sftp/jo/horizon/ on app4" >> /home/sftp/jo/glout.log
         ssh $HOST "/bin/rm /hello/world/temp/glout/filename_ofmultiplefiles*.txt"
      done
      else
         echo "No files to be moved from $HOST" >> /home/sftp/jo/glout.log
   fi
done
```

I need four files (with different names) to be moved but I am only getting the first one moved even though the log says it moved all four files. I am guessing it's overwritting the one file four times. But how can I get it to place the multiple files?

Comment: What's the relationship between `/hello/world/temp/` and `/er/d_d/temp/`?

Comment: Updated, it's the same.

Comment: So you're scp'ing the first file and then you delete them all before transferring the second?

Comment: I think that's the issue. I want to remove them after they are all transferred.

Comment: If you want to do something after all the files have transferred, put it after the loop

Comment: When you're satisified that it works, you can replace all of this with a simple `scp "$HOST:/hello/world/temp/glout/filename_ofmultiplefiles*.txt" "app4:/home/sftp/jo/horizon/"`

Comment: That worked thanks

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked out! Since it was a simple logical error unrelated to scp and copying files, I'm voting to close it as a simple typo bug to avoid confusing future readers trying to scp files